# Border Radius changes when setting CSS width using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The problem I'm having is that the `border-radius` of a `<div/>` gets removed when applying the css `width` property via jQuery. The `<div/>` that has the radius is also cropping off an `absolute` positioned `<div/>`. I've included an example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/SLvBZ/2/

Here is a similar example where it works for Twitter (log in first):
https://twitter.com/welcome/recommendations

Browser version: Chrome 26.0.1410.65

```
#SuggestProgressContainer {
    height: 27px;
    float: left;
    margin: 4px 20px 0 0;
    position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 247px;
    overflow: hidden;

    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

#SuggestProgressBar {
    width: 247px;
    height: 27px;
    background: #c6c6c6;
    border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
}

#SuggestProgress {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    border: 1px solid #068CE1;
    background: #0F93E7;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#1c9dee), to(#068ce1));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1c9dee, #068ce1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1c9dee, #068ce1);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1c9dee, #068ce1);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1c9dee, #068ce1);

    -webkit-transition: width 230ms ease-out;
       -moz-transition: width 230ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: width 230ms ease-out;
         -o-transition: width 230ms ease-out;
            transition: width 230ms ease-out;
}

#ProgressText {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 10px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0, .15);
}
```

Comment: Seems to work in FF 21.0 here.

Comment: Which browser are you using?  I'm not seeing the issue in your fiddle in Chrome.

Comment: I'm in Chrome. Version 26.0.1410.65

Comment: I see it in chrome 26.0.1410.65 and FF 20.0 on mac

Comment: Looks like a rendering bug, resizing the preview area fixes it.

Comment: I added the border radius to a few other elements, and here's my version that works: http://jsfiddle.net/SLvBZ/3/

Comment: @Johannes that sort of fixes it for one of the corners (top left) but not bottom left.

Comment: Seems this is the bug report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=71639

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [bug in webkit](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=71639) (or at least Chrome) with the combination of `border-radius`, `overflow: hidden` and `position` other than `static`. Your example link on twitter uses static position. So I'd say your only option is to use `position: static`. I modified your code to do so:

```
<div id="SuggestComplete">
   <div id="SuggestProgressContainer">
       <div id="SuggestProgressBar">
           <div id="SuggestProgress"></div>
       </div>
       <span id="ProgressText">Follow 5 collections</span>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="button">test</div>
```

CSS:

```
#SuggestProgressContainer {
    height: 27px;
    float: left;
    margin: 4px 20px 0 0;
    position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 247px;
    /*overflow: hidden;

    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;*/ /* removed here */
}

#SuggestProgressBar {
    width: 247px;
    height: 27px;
    background: #c6c6c6;
    border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;

    /* added overflow and border radius here */
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

#SuggestProgress {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    /*position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;*/ /* so it is static to prevent the bug */
    border: 1px solid #068CE1;
    background: #0F93E7;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#1c9dee), to(#068ce1));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1c9dee, #068ce1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1c9dee, #068ce1);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1c9dee, #068ce1);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1c9dee, #068ce1);

    -webkit-transition: width 230ms ease-out;
       -moz-transition: width 230ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: width 230ms ease-out;
         -o-transition: width 230ms ease-out;
            transition: width 230ms ease-out;
}
```

Which seems to work. [Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SLvBZ/21/).

The funny part is that the issue described in the bug report seems to be fixed because back then the problem occurred even without programmatically changing the `width`. But it looks like they forgot to solve the issue on rerender events too.